# SSO, the unknown

Tags: java, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I'm starting to work on a **SSO** solution for 3 different webapps we've produced and still maintain for the same client.

Thing is, all 3 store their users and login information in the same place through a **fourth separate application** which provides just basic restful api services. 
Which basically means that when one tries to log into, we actually call the rest service asking whether this username and password are correct.

In a way this fourth restful thingie already does *at least* half of the job we need.

What we need now is a way to let users log into webapp A, then follow a link (or simply type its url) to webapp B (or simply type its url) and get there already **logged** (or viceversa).

I've been reading a lot about **CAS** and **openID** or even **oauth** but can't really make up my mind about it. 
Is this **pattern** centralized? Decentralized?

My ten-thousand foot view suggests I would somehow just need to add this "missing feature" to our restful api server.

But how?

ps: these 3 are completely separated. deployed on different machines (2 of them run on glassfish, the other one runs on tomcat). different domains too.

pps: they're all spring-driven webapps (hence they use **spring-security**)

ppps: as of today, there are other webapps using our restul api (non spring, non java). 
this sso solution might have to be ready to handle those too.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah it sounds like you need a "true" single sign on system rather than just a centralized credential repository. As you mentioned there are several options:

1. OpenId - more suited to an internet type application in which you
   want to allow users to log into your systems with credentials that
   are maintained by a third party. Stackoverflow is a classic example. 
   You can sign in with your google account etc.
2. Oauth provides Pseudo authentication and sso - whereas OpenId says
   "this is user x" oauth says "this user has access to x's
   information" ... so you can assume that the user is x.
3. [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas), [Cloudseal](http://www.cloudseal.com), [OpenAM](http://forgerock.com/openam.html) etc all provide true single
   sign on and are suitable for an intranet or extranet environment.
   CAS and Cloudseal have especially good Spring support.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, I'm reading spring-security docs on CAS integration. At one point (22.2.1) starts describing step-by-step the usual interaction. It then says _"The CasAuthenticationEntryPoint will redirect the user's browser to the CAS server..."._
I do not want that to happen.
Users should still log-in through OUR website.
**No redirection is wanted.**
Any clue with that?

Comment: Just found out about so called CAS Gateway feature. Guess it's what I need

Answer (score 0):

- Trusted site (relying party (RP) in white list - app a,b,c in your case) make request (redirect) to main site (provider - "fourth separate application") with a return url.
- Main site make sure request (returnURL) is from white list of domains
- Log user (if not logged, displaying login form), mark user as logged in database and add temporary token to user database.
- Main site return (redirect) to RP with token.
- RP look into database using token, logs user and deletes token.

SSOff also easy: just check on every request into user database into bool record (userLogged). NO REDIRECTS. On logout simply change record (userLogged) to false and every site will know.