# I have two java applications with different domain names. How can i authenticate to both with one login

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, struts, tomcat6, single-sign-on

I was asked to do a peculiar task today. I have two Java applications developed using struts framework. My boss asked me to provide a link to the second application in the first one and when a user clicks it, he needs to be redirected to the second application.. ok this is easy. But the user should not be required to authenticate on the second application again. How can this be acheived?

Note: the same Tomcat server where my 2 applications are deployed has other applications hosted which do not need single sign on.

Comment: Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152708/sso-the-unknown as a start?

Answer (score 1):

There are many Single Sign On (SSO) solutions. It depends  on your environment. Many server containers offer custom SSO solutions. For example, if your both applications run in Tomcat see an easy to implement SSO: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/host.html#Single_Sign_On

Comment: Both my applications run on the same tomcat server, they authenticate with the same user name and password for the users. Im reading through the link you provided me and now i have more questions. If i have multiple applications running on Tomcat 6 (on windows server) and if only 2 of them need to have single sign on.. what is a good way of doing it. The client im working for has a default setup of Tomcat and nothing has been customised.